# Not sure how to save prices in one shot in vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-8

I have a table that lists out all my products and their prices and I have the prices as input
and what I would like to do is, when I click on save then I need to be able to save all those prices that I changed at
one time.

I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

Here is my code

```
    <template>
    <div>
        <table class="table table-sm table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="product in products">
            <td>{{product.name}}</td>
            <td>
                <input  @change="onChange(product)" v-model="product.prices">
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <div>
        <div class="btn btn-success" @click="updatePrices()">
        Save Prices
        </div>
    </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    export default {
        props: ['products'],
        data() {
            return {
                product: {
                    price: null
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            updatePrices(){
                console.log(this.products.price);
            }

        },
        mounted(){

        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: on `save`, do you want to get all products with updated price?

Comment: So what I need done is when I click save it then will post to a function on the backend which then saves the prices to the corresponding product

Comment: what backend tech are you using? does your backend allow mass collections save / update function? check those function first before ask questions. you need to improve your question with proper information to get quick help

Comment: I'm using laravel

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about two parts of data passing.

1. From Vue Component to Vue Parent.
2. From Vue Client to Server.

And also, you may be confused with component **data** and **props**

You can check my answer

```js
//component
Vue.component('price-table', {
  props:[
    'parentProducts',
  ],
  data: function() {
    return {
     products:[]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    updatePrice(){
            console.log('update prices from component to parent');
            console.log(this.products);
      this.$emit('update-prices', this.products);
    }
  },
  mounted:function(){
    console.log('pass products from parent to component');
    this.products = this.parentProducts;
  }
});

//parent
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
        products:[
      {
        name:'Apple',
        price:'10'
      },
      {
        name:'Banana',
        price:'12'
      },
      {
        name:'Coconut',
        price:'20'
      },
      ]
   }),
  methods:{
    savePricesToServer(products){
        console.log('save prices to server');
        console.log(products);
      //do ajax here
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Price Table</h2>
  <price-table 
    inline-template 
    :parent-products="products"
    v-on:update-prices="savePricesToServer"
   >
    <div>
    <table border='1' width="100%">
      <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="(product, productIndex) in products" :key="productIndex">
        <td>{{ product.name}}</td>
        <td>
        <input type="number" v-model="product.price">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
      <button @click="updatePrice">Update Price</button>
    </div>
  </price-table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It is showing how to use custom event to pass data from component back to parent https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html